# Editing and compiling 7-zip in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, compilation, 7zip

It seems the source code for many applications is not friendly with Visual Studio 2010 or 2012, or for anything GUI based for that matter, probably my knowledge is at fault there.

**Programs and versions:**

Windows 7 Ultimate X64 SP1

7zip source version: 9.20 (recommended) (removed "-OPT:NOWIN98")

Microsoft Visual Studio 11 (2012) version: 4.5.50709

Microsoft Visual Studio 10 (2010) version: 4.5.50709 SP1Rel

**Problem:**

Now, the problem is that I try to load the "Build.mak" file into either program and it asks me if I want to update the files so they can work with the application. I went through it's option-less process and I get the errors below. I have edited out the "-OPT:NOWIN98" from "Build.mak", but it didn't change the errors produced or anything else.

---

Overview
Project Path    Errors  Warnings    Messages
    Build   Build.mak   2   0   1
    ..\CPP\Build.mak        1   0   0

Solution and projects

- Build
  Message: Build.mak: End tag 'xs:choice' does not match the start tag 'xs:sequence'.
  Build.mak: Project upgrade failed.
  Show 1 additional messages
- ..\CPP\Build.mak
  Message: The following error has occurred during XML parsing: File: F:\7zip\CPP\Build.mak Line: 1 Column: 1 Error Message: Incorrect document syntax. The file'F:\7zip\CPP\Build.mak' has failed to load.

---

It's the same for both programs, so I'm guessing either some pre-steps need to be done or the application just will never appreciate being edited in the latest Visual Studios.
Is there any way to fix this so it loads the file correctly and can compile the application?